# Finding points of inflection on a 2d Bezier curve

Tags: c++, math, bezier

I need to determine points of inflection (points where the curvature changes) on a 2d Bezier curve, parameterized by **t**, 0 <= **t** <= 1, if they exist. My original method was to sample along the curve, evaluating second derivatives and finding the point where the derivative's sign changes.

```
2DVector curvature1, curvature2;
for (double t = 0, t <= 1.0; t += STEP) {
    curvature1 = bezier.CurvatureAt(t);
    curvature2 = bezier.CurvatureAt(t + (STEP/2.0 >= 1.0 ? 0 : t + STEP/2.0));
    if (isNegative(curvature1) ? isPositive(curvature2) : isNegative(curvature2)) {
        inflection_point = t;
    }
 }
```

where CurvatureAt() is a method that evaluates the second derivative of the bezier at **t**, but as the bezier curve is a vector valued function the derivative is returned as a 2D vector (not std::vector, a 2D vector class). I dont know how to interpret "where the sign changes" for vectors. Basically i dont know how to write isNegative or isPositive in the above snippet.

are there any other ways to find points of inflection on a 2d Bezier curve?

I dont think its possible to determine a closed form solution to this problem because the Bezier can be of arbitrary degree, however please correct me if I'm wrong here.

Comment: What do you mean by 'point of inflection'?  An obvious meaning would be 'maximum extent in x or y direction', but I can imagine others.  There will be a mathematical answer to this question (ie an answer in closed mathematical form), though there isn't one obvious on eg the [mathworld page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BezierCurve.html).  If you can find it, that solution would be both more accurate and faster to calculate than an iterative solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Curvature is related to but not the same as second derivative.

The signed curvature of a parametric curve `P(t) = (x(t), y(t))` is actually a number and is defined as:

```
k(t) = (x'y'' - x''y') / (x' * x' + y' * y')^(3/2)
```

If you use this formula your original idea should work.

Answer (score 1):

To determine the points of inflection on a bezier, find the time or times in the interval (0, 1) [excluding the endpoints of course] for which the cross product of the first and second derivatives of the parametric equation of the bezier is zero i.e. f' X f'' = 0.

This is noted in various sources like [this page](http://www.caffeineowl.com/graphics/2d/vectorial/cubic-inflexion.html) and p 4 of [this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.86.8080&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need such a loop.
According to [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature#Local_expressions), you can compute at any point the curvature of a Bezier curve. As a Bezier curve has a polynomial expression, you can easily compute when the sign of the curvature changes.