# Extrusion Effect For Bezier Curves In JS

Tags: javascript, svg, bezier

is there a tool available for JS to perform a simple extrusion effect to composite cubic Bezier curves (which I will refer to as composite curves), like they are used in SVGs, similar to figure (5) in the picture below?  I want the result as a composite curve, not just the rasterization.

[image]

The mathematical formulation for this would be [dilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilation_(morphology)) with a structural element in the form of a line segment (which can be w.l.o.g. be the unit interval [0, 1] embedded in R^2).  So given a set A of points in the plane whose boundary can be described by a composite curve, I am looking for a composite curve describing the set A' := [p ∈ R^2 : ∃q ∈ A : p − q ∈ [0, 1]] of points which are to the right of a point from A, but not further than distance 1.

I imagine one must first find all points on a Bezier segment where the derivative of the curve is horizontal (unless the curve is a horizontal straight line) and divide the curve there.  Then horizontal straight lines are inserted between certain (new or old) curve segments.  If the shape has holes, the holes are just duplicated, moved to the right and intersected with the original hole.  Possibly related to [finding the points of inflection.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11465703/finding-points-of-inflection-on-a-2d-bezier-curve)

Comment: There's no magic - you either do the extrusion math to create a new shape (hard) or you can layer multiple copies of the original shape behind itself using a filter. Here is a tool with simple source so you can see how a filter like that is constructed. https://codepen.io/mullany/full/qOqxpG

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Can you recommend me any ressources to learn the math needed for this?  I think basically I need two things: (i) Split Bezier curve at given point and (ii) find all points in Bezier with given derivative.  The first part should be easy, but what would be the idea for the second part?  Possibly some root finding algorithm?

Comment: Not exactly what you asked for, but check out three.js for a general 3D library.

Comment: Yeah, but I really want the result in nice Bezier curves.  My guess is that three.js also converts the Beziers in polygonal chains to create the polygons from there.  This seems not too hard to do by hand.

Comment: what do you mean with "I want the result in nice bezier curves" though? because it sounds like you just want something that offsets and then unifies an arbitrary closed path for use as a background underneath that path. Which path segments that consists of makes no difference. Having said that: this is what graphics libraries are for, see if three.js or paper.js or p5.js or any of the other ones let you do this.

Comment: With nice Beziers I mean that the result should contain cubic and quadratic Beziers if needed.  For example, if I input an approximation of a circle like [this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d9/Circle_and_cubic_bezier.svg) and want to extrude it to the top left, I expect the algorithm to break two of the cubic Beziers in the middle and insert straight lines.  The breaking part of cubic Beziers seems not so hard, but how to find the points where to break them?  Possibly [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11465703/finding-points-of-inflection-on-a-2d-bezier-curve).

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I don't understand, what you mean with background underneath?  I see that offset and unifying can be done easily with e.g. paper.js, but I don't see how to add the missing parts?  Also, I don't know if three.js or p5.js can hand me back the Bezier curves of their transformations?  I don't want to just draw the result but really have all the curve data.  Paper.js can do that with `exportJSON`.

Comment: Your image shows a procedure where a shape is created, and then the original shape is rendered on top of that, so you're either looking for how to create that "background layer", or you want to know how to create _many_ different shapes that match individual "faces" that you're showing for the final orange picture (and then you'd still have to draw the original on top, of course). I would recommend editing your question to actually include what you're trying to solve: draw it out (or wireframe it in SVG as runnable snippet) and show _that_ in your post, to explain what part is not working yet.